# Elisp `url-copy-file` sometimes downloads garbage?

Tags: emacs, download, elisp, corruption

I am writing some Elisp code that downloads files using `url-copy-file`, and most of the time it works fine, but sometimes the contents of the file end up being the http headers, e.g. the downloaded file has the following contents:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2013 20:54:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Status: 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://render.github.com
```

Or sometimes the following is appended to the end of an otherwise correctly-downloaded file:

```
0

- Peer has closed the GnuTLS connection
```

However, when these things occur, the function seems to return just fine, so there is no way for me to verify that the file has really been downloaded. Is there any more reliable way to download a file in elisp (without shelling out to wget/curl/whatever)?

Comment: What if you try `url-retrieve`? This seems to be a lower-level function for doing the same thing. `url-copy-file` tries to cater for different callers (tries to guess them indirectly, by the presence of certain artefacts) and could get confused.

Comment: @wvxvw `url-retrieve` also shares this problem.

Comment: This is not a known problem, so please `M-x report-emacs-bug` to try and help us track it down and kill the bugger.

Comment: Reported: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-11/msg00758.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended, I have reported this as a bug: lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-11/msg00758.html